# Unable to start the "HelloWorld" NativeScript app on an Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, nativescript

This is a continuation of my previous question posted here:

[Can I "force" the Android Simulator to always use the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173762/can-i-force-the-android-simulator-to-always-use-the-same-port)

I kind of found a workaround for the issue described in that question. It's temporary, as it exposes the virtual machine where I am trying to run this NativeScript development environment, but for now, it will do.

I don't see that error but I have run into a different thing and I want to ask your help with it.

Running the

```
>tns doctor
```

command, I see that all issues are perfectly installed and up-to-date:

[image: tns doctor screen shot]

In Android Studio -> AVD Manager, I see the emulator properly installed:

[image]

I also see it in my Visual Studio Code terminal:

[image]

So far, so good. If I try to run my application, I get this result:

[image]

I try to execute the command suggested on the first line. I get this:

[image]

I also tried debugging and targetting my emulator. Same kind of response:

[image]

I have configured 2 GB of RAM on the emulator. Presumably, that is not the cause of this crash.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get out of this situation? So far this has been extremely frustrating.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: You read "emulator-5554, Status: Unreachable" as "So far, so good."? I'm not sure I would agree...

Comment: Thank you, Ian. A lot of suggestions on that other thread. Looks like many people are struggling with the same issue. I am working my way through the list of all those suggestions, but the few that I already tried did not resolve my issue. Maybe I'll ask for more suggestions on that thread. As for the "So far, so good" comment, I thought that the system is looking for an actual device that is connected to the USB. Since I do not have anything like that, I thought that the "Unreachable" status would be valid.

Comment: There seems to be issue with your emulator and connection to it. This causes both of the issues you've described (here and in the other thread).
Can you try creating another emulator from Android Studio? Can you run the current one from there?

Comment: @Vladimirov Thanks for your comment. I've deleted and recreated many emulators so far. I've even replaced the target several times. I tried Q, Pie and Oreo, both x86 and x86_64 images. I switched between emulators with Play Store support and emulators without. Same results with every single one. I can start the simulator from Android Studio. The emulator also starts on its own when I try to run my little app in Visual Studio Code. I really don't know what else to try. Maybe I will start a new question since this one is now closed.